# GH pages deploy via admin interface

Tags: github, deployment, publishing, github-pages, lektor

The video on 
https://www.getlektor.com/docs/deployment/travisci/

describes the set-up nicely.

Is there an option to make run the whole local git committing & pushing via the publish link in the admin interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, clicking the deploy button in the admin interface, once you've set up the deploy target, works the same as on the lektor command line.